# Assign variable to @IBOutlet UIView

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

Is it possible to set a variable to an IBOutlet? 
I have a button that I want to display a view as a dropdown. The dropdown will be different if the user has an account or is a guest.   I was hoping to do the following:

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var profileMenu: UIView!
  @IBOutlet weak var guestMenu: UIView!

  var currentMenu: UIView = self.profileMenu

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if(user.registered){
      currentMenu = self.profileMenu
    } else {
      currentMenu = self.guestMenu
    }
  }

  // toggle visibility on the currentMenu UIView
  @IBAction func didClickProfileButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    currentMenu.hidden = !currentMenu.hidden
  }
```

Comment: When you tried that code, did you get the result you expected?

Comment: No, it complains that HomeViewController does not have a member named profileMenu when I try to assign it. This line specifically: `var currentMenu: UIView = self.profileMenu`

Comment: Well that is a very important detail to add to your question then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here has nothing to do with `@IBOutlet`s or `UIView`s. The problem is how you are setting your default values for member variables.

This won't work:

```
var profileMenu: UIView!
var currentMenu: UIView = self.profileMenu
```

You can't reference self as the default value like that, especially when the other member variable is not even assigned yet!

Instead, why not make `currentMenu` an unwrapped optional, and just assign it in `viewDidLoad`?

```
var currentMenu: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  if(user.registered){
    currentMenu = self.profileMenu
  } else {
    currentMenu = self.guestMenu
  }
}
```

This should work because `viewDidLoad` will always get called, and the `if/else` ensures that it always assigns one of the two values.

Comment: This worked. I was declaring `var currentMenu: UIView` without the conditional unwrap and getting errors on the class level say it did not have an init method. So I assumed all declarations needed to be set to a value, sometimes I got away with using `nil` until I set it to the correct value in `viewDidLoad`. I need to read up on unwrapped optionals, I don't quite understand it.  Thanks.

Comment: `!` in a type means: when I read this value, always assume it has a value. But that value is still allowed to be `nil`. This means your class can initialize and have that value be `nil`. But then later, before you read form that property you set it to a real value. And now you can read from that variable and assume it's not `nil`. It's a good practice for anything you will setup in `viewDidLoad` but not `init`.